# Image src firefox not showing, absolute path

Tags: html, path, image, absolute

ASP.NET Application

I am having some confusion with showing images. IE is fully working when loading img. Firefox does not show images on production server.

The img url generated is on server:

```
\chartings\charts\temp/generatedchart_img.jpg
```

I have noticed when I run on localhost publish flips the src url:

```
/chartings/charts/temp\generatedchart_img.jpg
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the url should only have forward slashes:

```
/chartings/charts/temp/generatedchart_img.jpg
```

Comment: I think that when firefox finds the \ it thinks that's a part of the filname, not a folder break so it look for the file `temp\generatedchart_img.jpg` inside the folder `/chartings/charts/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my url is generated from c# code behind. `this.txtChartImageFilename.Value = this.chartings+ @"\" + csiChart.FileManager.FileName + ".jpg";` where this.chartings i s`/chartings/charts/temp`. Why does it work in IE? does it convert the backslash?

Comment: I have no idea why IE dose what it dose... But in your code you are adding a ` \ ` First step would be to change `this.txtChartImageFilename.Value = this.chartings+ @"\" + csiChart.FileManager.FileName + ".jpg";` to `this.txtChartImageFilename.Value = this.chartings+ @"/" + csiChart.FileManager.FileName + ".jpg";`